# How make responsive grid with images

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 column and 2 row of images (all images have **different** size) on big screen. 
But it is wrong in small screen.

What is solution suggest bootstrap ?

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
        <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Index", "Artist")?id=' + id}" class="portfolio-link">
            <div class="caption">
                <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                <br />
                <span data-bind="text: views"></span> Views
            </div>
            <img data-bind="attr { src: image }" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way more complicated than it seems. So basically you want to display 2 colums on extra small devices and 3 colums on small, medium and large devices and in the same time the images should align without any spaces.

As far as i know, if you want to use bootstrap only you can achieve it like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs portfolio-item">
    @foreach ( $artists as $key => $artist )
        @if ($key % 3 == 0)
            <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Index", "Artist")?id=' + $artist->id}" class="portfolio-link">
                <div class="caption">
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    <br />
                    <span data-bind="text: views"></span> Views
                </div>
                <img data-bind="attr { src: image }" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </a>
        @endif

    @endforeach                
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs portfolio-item">
    @foreach ( $artists as $key => $artist )
        @if ($key % 3 == 1)
            <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Index", "Artist")?id=' + $artist->id}" class="portfolio-link">
                <div class="caption">
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    <br />
                    <span data-bind="text: views"></span> Views
                </div>
                <img data-bind="attr { src: image }" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </a>
        @endif

    @endforeach    
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs portfolio-item">
    @foreach ( $artists as $key => $artist )
        @if ($key % 3 == 2)
            <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Index", "Artist")?id=' + $artist->id}" class="portfolio-link">
                <div class="caption">
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    <br />
                    <span data-bind="text: views"></span> Views
                </div>
                <img data-bind="attr { src: image }" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </a>
        @endif

    @endforeach   
</div>
```

And add this to work for extra small devices:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 visible-xs portfolio-item">
    @foreach ( $artists as $key => $artist )
        @if ($key % 2 == 0)
            <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Index", "Artist")?id=' + $artist->id}" class="portfolio-link">
                <div class="caption">
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    <br />
                    <span data-bind="text: views"></span> Views
                </div>
                <img data-bind="attr { src: image }" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </a>
        @endif

    @endforeach                
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 visible-xs portfolio-item">
    @foreach ( $artists as $key => $artist )
        @if ($key % 2 == 1)
            <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Index", "Artist")?id=' + $artist->id}" class="portfolio-link">
                <div class="caption">
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    <br />
                    <span data-bind="text: views"></span> Views
                </div>
                <img data-bind="attr { src: image }" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </a>
        @endif

    @endforeach   
</div>
```

Comment: It definetly works, i've already implement it on a website witch is only on the dev version so i can't show you, but when i will put it on production i could send you the link to check it out. It a very cool effect. I have 4 colums on large desktops (lg), 3 colums on small desktops (md), 2 colums on tablets (sm) and 1 colum for mobiles (xs)

Comment: I thought  it should be use only col-XX without hidden side

Comment: Well no. You have 2 blocks as you wrote, one containig two colums visible only on xs screens and another one containing 3 colums visible on all other devices except xs screens. So its kinda dupplicate. You can't do that with bootstrap if you want that type of grid.